# not able to save push notification payload in ios if app is forced killed by user

Tags: ios

All
push notification is  not coming in below method(although it is coming in notification bar) if app is forced killed by user

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))handler
```

but it is working fine in case of background and foreground.

1. is there any way to save push payload in case of application is forced killed by the user and push arrived at device ??.

As i observed WhatsApp is able to show data inside application if app is forced killed by user. i forced  killed the WhatsApp application and when notification came i off the internet connectivity then went to application . i am able to see the notification and data in side app.

2. how it is happening   in whatsApp application??

Other 
Please give me some solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if your app is kiled and you get notification and when you tap on notification banner or app icon for open it again you will get notification info dictionary in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method of Appdelegate by using `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey`

Comment: WhatsApp is a VoIP app, so it is probably using PushKit.  Pushkit will relaunch a terminated app if a push notification arrives